# Add Checkbox to Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I want to add checkboxes in a word 2010 .doc file and also keep everything else editable. 
I tried the following options from Developer->Restrict Editing:

- "Filling in forms" but it blocks editing on the entire document
- "No changes (Read only)" to block editing on sections, but the checkbox doesn't work

Is this possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkbox in word 2010.

1. Go to File > Options.

[image]

2. Customize Ribbon > (RIGHT SIDE) uncheck Developer, RE-Check Developer > OK

[image]

3. Go to Developer Tab in your Ribbon (to the right) > Click on Check Mark Icon.

[image]

4. Enjoy.